# How to get postgres to use index for wild card query on JSONB column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in a postgres DB that looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE docs {
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  doc JSONB
};
```

The JSON documents look like the following:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "name": "something",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I want to run wildcard queries on the table like follows:

```
SELECT id FROM docs WHERE doc -> 'meta' ->> 'name' LIKE '%Adam%';
```

However, this search is not using any index. I have tried creating indexes like the following:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON docs USING GIN ((doc));
CREATE INDEX myindex ON docs USING GIN ((doc -> 'meta' -> 'name'));
CREATE INDEX myindex ON docs ((doc -> 'meta' -> 'name'));
```

When I try to 'explain' the query, I always find that index is not used. How do I execute this query and have postgres use the index ?

Comment: You need to use a [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.8) to support such a wildcard

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I did the following:

CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX myindex ON docs USING GIN ((doc -> 'meta' ->> 'name') gin_trgm_ops);

This solved my problem. Please add your answer below. I will accept it.

Comment: Note that you'd have to create a trigram index for every attribute of the sonb`that you want to search in that way. If that number is high, performance may suffer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , that is correct. Fortunately, in my use case it is acceptable - we have just a few attributes like this.